# Correct way to post data via api when using Kendo UI MVVM

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

**Introduction**

I am working with kendo-ui.Data loading perfectly in grid using web-api.I am doing one thing more which is to "Post" or create new record.I have set this up using [This Example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/remote-binding).

**Problem**

Now, when i add new record/item and then click on submit button(which only show my alerts and console messages) my insertion failed and i don't have related error messages. I have checked schema, modal etc but again can't find any problem.

> Can this be a modal issue?

**HTM**

```
<div id="form-container">
<div class="demo-section k-content">
<input type='text' data-bind='value:Name' name='Project Name' />
<input data-value-primitive="true" data-source="dataSourceList" data-bind="value:Status" data-role="dropdownlist" />
<button data-bind="click: save" class="k-button k-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**Modified Script**

```
 var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        dataSourceList: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read:
                    {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "dropdown/projectstatus",
                        dataType: "json",
                    },
                create: {
                    url: function () {
                        return crudServiceBaseUrl + "Project/?firmid=" + firmid + "&createdby=" + clientid
                    },
                    type: "POST"
                },
                batch: true,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ProjectId",
                        fields: {
                            ProjectId: { from: "ProjectId", editable: true, nullable: true, type: "guid" }
                           , Status: { from: "Status", editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" }
                           , Name: { from: "Name", editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        }),
        save: function () {
            this.dataSourceList.add({ Status: this.get("Status"), Name: this.get("Name")});
            console.log(this.dataSourceList.add({ Status: this.get("Status"), Name: this.get("Name") }));
            this.dataSourceList.sync();
            console.log(this.dataSourceList.transport.options.schema);
            },
    });
    kendo.bind($("#form-container"), viewModel);
```

**Console messages Screen(in code above)**

[image: console msgs]

I have been trying for some time but couldn't solve this problem.If someone has idea about this please help or any reference, it will be appreciated.Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try to change your create part. Url become only `url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "Project/"` and then add after type the data property: `data: { firmid: firmid, createdby: clientid  }